# Displaying result HTML page after AJAX post

Tags: javascript, ajax, post, html-rendering

```
   <form onsubmit="geoFindLat()" name="search-form">
        <div class="input-group form-group form-group-lg">
          <input type="text" name="search" class="form-control col-lg-6" placeholder="Search Books" id="q">
          <span class="input-group-btn"><button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit" ><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </span>
       </div>
   </form>
```

I have the above html form `search.html`. When user enters text and presses enter, a javascript function is invoked which then gets the lat/lng and the search text.

```
function geoFindLat() {
    var input = document.forms["search-form"]["search"].value;

    function success(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/search",
            data: {
                latitude: latitude,
                longitude: longitude,
                q: input
            },
            error: function () {
            },
            success: function (response) {
            },
            complete: function () {
            }

        })
      };

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
    }
```

Upon success, the POST method is invoked which retrieves the lat,lng and query_name values and prints it. I want the page to be redirected to results.html which doesn't happen. The search.html pages seems to get reloaded all time.

```
class Search(SearchRequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        self.redirect('/')

    def post(self):
        query_name = self.request.get('q')
        lat = self.request.get('latitude')
        lng = self.request.get('longitude')
        print query_name, lat,lng
        doc = //** SOME OPERATION 
        tpl_values = {
           'lat': lat,
           'lng': lng,
           'doc': doc
        }

         self.render('search_result/results.html', **tpl_values)
```

Please help.

Comment: In your success callback function, just add `window.location = "results.html"`. But, of course that page won't have any data from the first page unless you somehow pass that data to it.

Comment: that wouldn't let me achieve the result of operations which i intend to do within the Search class.

Comment: You could relocate that class into the results page.